# GVM: Issue when installing GVM in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: installation, ubuntu-14.04, gvm

I am new to `GVM` according to its documentation when i run the following command to install `GVM` there is no output display on terminal like:

```
james@james-K52F:~$ curl -s get.gvmtool.net | bash
james@james-K52F:~$
```

When i run the command after `CURL`, i am getting following error:

```
james@james-K52F:~$ gvm
No command 'gvm' found, but there are 20 similar ones
gvm: command not found
```

When i hit the `CURL` command without `-s` flag, then getting following error:

```
james@james-K52F:~$ curl get.gvmtool.net | bash
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time    Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to get.gvmtool.net port 80: Network is unreachable
```

How could i resolve these issue and install `GVM` on my system?

**Update**

This problem, is solved using following command:

```
james@james-K52F:~$ sudo curl --ipv4 get.gvmtool.net | bash
```

But now the problem is that, when i run the above command, `GVM installation` process is start but the following error are produces:

```
------------------
Create candidate directories...
Prime the config file...
Download script archive...
Extract script archive...
[/home/james/.gvm/tmp/res-2.4.1.zip]
 End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
 a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
 latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/james/.gvm/tmp/res-2.4.1.zip or
    /home/james/.gvm/tmp/res-2.4.1.zip.zip, and cannot find /home/james/.gvm/tmp/res-2.4.1.zip.ZIP, period.
Install scripts...
mv: cannot stat ‘/home/james/.gvm/tmp/stage/gvm-init.sh’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘/home/james/.gvm/tmp/stage/gvm-*’: No such file or directory
Attempt update of bash profiles...
Attempt update of zsh profiles...
All done!

Please open a new terminal, or run the following in the existing one:

source "/home/james/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh"

Then issue the following command:

gvm help

Enjoy!!!
```

After that when i run `source "/home/james/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh"` on new terminal i got the following error:

```
james@james-K52F:~$ source "/home/james/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh"
bash: /home/james/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh: No such file or directory
```

its seems like, out bash file is not downloaded from web. I think this is the problem with `curl` command or something else?

Comment: I think i've the same error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805269/gvm-install-error

Comment: What version of curl are you using? I'm on 7.35.0

Comment: @emeraldjava my curl version is `curl 7.35.0 `.

Answer (score 6):

CURL is unable to resolve gvmtool.net because it gets redirected to sdkman.io

sdk was formerly known as gvm.
Instead of gvm try using sdk for installation of Groovy, Grails, etc.
Try the below command

`$ curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash`

And to install grails, refer this--
https://grails.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem in your download.

use a "proxy " to connect and download it correctly, by this command

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```